# Input operators and operands into two different stacks

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I want get an expression as input from a user using Scanner or anything more suitable, and push operators in one stack, and operands in another.

so if I have something like: 52+3*(2-1)
I want to evaluate it using stacks.

I thought of reading the whole line as a string and changing it to a char[] but the problem is the 52 would be read as two separate chars.

Comment: You have to scan and then parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the whole line at once and then use a StringTokenizer to get the individual operators/operands.

```
    String example = "52+3*(2-1)";
    String delim = "[/*-+()]";

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(example, delim, true);
    while(st.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        // check if it's an operator or operand and add it to the appropriate stack
    }
```